# pandas reshape date sequence

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, reshape, melt

I have table with factor and time interval. What I want to do is to get long table with each date in interval between `START_DATE` and `END_DATE`.

```
dt_in = pd.DataFrame({'factor':['A','B'],
          'START_DATE':[pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01'),pd.Timestamp('2016-02-05')],
          'END_DATE':[pd.Timestamp('2015-01-04'),pd.Timestamp('2016-02-07')]})

    END_DATE    START_DATE  factor
0   2015-01-04  2015-01-01  A
1   2016-02-07  2016-02-05  B
```

I want to have output table like this one:

```
dt_out = pd.DataFrame({'factor': ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B'],
                   'DATE': ['2015-01-01', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-03', '2015-01-04',
                            '2016-02-05', '2016-02-06', '2016-02-07']})
    DATE    factor
0   2015-01-01  A
1   2015-01-02  A
2   2015-01-03  A
3   2015-01-04  A
4   2016-02-05  B
5   2016-02-06  B
6   2016-02-07  B
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) for reshaping and then `groupby` with [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html) for filling `dates`:

```
df = pd.melt(dt_in, id_vars='factor', value_name='DATE')
       .set_index('DATE')
       .drop('variable',axis=1)

print (df)
           factor
DATE             
2015-01-04      A
2016-02-07      B
2015-01-01      A
2016-02-05      B

print (df.groupby('factor')
         .resample('1D')
         .ffill()
         .reset_index(drop=True, level=0)
         .reset_index())

        DATE factor
0 2015-01-01      A
1 2015-01-02      A
2 2015-01-03      A
3 2015-01-04      A
4 2016-02-05      B
5 2016-02-06      B
6 2016-02-07      B
```

Notice:

*This funcionality is new in [pandas 0.18.1](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0181-deferred-ops).*

Comment: Excellent! Thank you